# WordPress Query group by post_types

Tags: wordpress, loops, search

Is it possible to order or group WP_Query by post types?

I'm making a search result page and what i want is example:

PAGES:

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

POSTS

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

Custom Post type:

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter__posts_orderby', 10, 2 );

function filter__posts_orderby( $orderby, $wp_query ) {
    if( ! $wp_query->is_admin && $wp_query->is_search ) :
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby =
            "
            CASE WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'page' THEN '1' 
                 WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post' THEN '2' 
                 WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'your_custom_post_type' THEN '3' 
                 WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'your_custom_post_type' THEN '4' 
            ELSE {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type END ASC, 
            {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title ASC";
    endif;
    return $orderby;
}
```

May be this will help you !

And Below is the code to Add your Custom Post Type in Search Result :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','action__pre_get_posts' );

function action__pre_get_posts($wp_query){
  if ( !is_admin() && is_main_query() && is_search() ){
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type'=>array('post','your_custom_post_type','page' ) );
  }
}
```

Also Place this code in your functions.php file of active theme.

Comment: Thanks think here i can make a start, but I need to make a foreach loop of all post types, but i think i can fix it. But how do i use this function in WP_Query?

Comment: You need to place this code in functions.php file of your active theme.

Comment: Yes i have added the code in functions.php but how can i use it on the search.php. tried: filter__posts_orderby('',have_posts()); but if print_r(); than i see only the code which i have added in functions.php

Comment: Do not edit search.php file, leave it as it is. And check my recent edits in this answer.

Comment: The custom post type is allready in the results, But i want to group them by post types..